# How to create stand alone scheduled task on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, scheduled-tasks

I would like to create a scheduled task in AWS and only pay for it when it runs. What I would like to accomplish is at a certain time, on a certain each week, I want to log in to a website and perform some very simple tasks. If I were writing a script, I would write this in Python, but I'm not sure how I would do this on AWS.

Per my Google searches, there seem to be multiple ways to do this, so I'm not sure what the most straightforward and cheapest way to do this is. Are there any experts able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

You would use AWS EventBridge to schedule the task, and [trigger an AWS Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-run-lambda-schedule.html) (which you can write in Python) to perform your task. You will only be charged for the time the Lambda function is running.

There are other solutions such as triggering an ECS Fargate task, instead of a Lambda function, but your specific use case is a classic task that people use AWS Lambda to perform.